# How can I create a fast, real-time, fixed length glowing ray?

Tags: opengl-es, glow, bloom

Similar to the disintegrate skill in Diablo 3. It should not light other objects in scene. Just glowing and animated. Like in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_c4x6aQAG8.

Should I use pack of pre-computed glow sources textures for each frame of ray animation like in this article http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html and put it in bloom shader?

[image]

Is there any other efficient ways to achive this effect? I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should try implementing it the way you suggest.

Another way would be to create the animated ray in an art program. Export it to a sprite sheet and just use a textured quad to display the animation where you need it. That would be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera will always see the ray almost perpendicular you can use just one large quad, but if you want volume when seen from other angles try using three or four intersecting large quads. This quads intersect in the middle of the quad (if seen from actor perspective we should see an star like structure).

Take a look at the wire-frame near the thrusters, those polygons are used to create a kind-of-volumetric-effect there. http://cdn1.eveonline.com/www/newssystem/media/2954/3217/10.jpg